# Toggle the border color of an input element based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the border color of the `input` element turn red **only** when the value of the input is zero. Here is my code:

```
const custom = () => {
    if(individual.value <= 1) {
        error.style.display = 'block'
        individual.style.borderColor = 'red'
    } else if(individual.value >= 1) {
        error.style.display = 'none'
        individual.style.borderColor = 'hsl(172, 67%, 45%)'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your input element. What type is it?

Comment: I guess `if ... else` is sufficient, no need for `else if`

Comment: also, `individual.value <= 1` and `individual.value >= 1` is somewhat illogical, if value is 1 it considers it as "error". I think it should be `individual.value < 1` and `individual.value >= 1`

Comment: The code in so far as you have given it works OK (as far as it goes, see @GrafiCode comment) so there is some problem with your surrounding HTML or JS. Look at your browser devtools inspect facility console to ensure you have no JS errors.

Comment: tbh there are many points where this script could fail which my answer should cover. for once it does not check for a change of the input. the next big major issue is, that an input will return a string not an integer if you type into the input field. So the first statement will always be true unless you convert the string to an integer with a `+` or `parseInt`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need an EventListener to listen to an input change: `inputElement.addEventListener`
- Than you need to get the value of the input as an Integer: `+inputElement.value`
- After that you need an `if/else`-statement or an conditional ternary operator
- Use classList to apply changesby adding/removing a class:

```js
let ele = document.querySelector('input');

ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let val = +ele.value;
  if (val <= 1) {
    ele.classList.add('error');
  } else {
    ele.classList.remove('error');
  }
})
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number step="1"">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created two input fields, both of `type` `number`. I created a general purpose handler, `handleNumberInput(e)` to listen for `input` events.

In the handler, you can compare the value of the input field to `0` using `valueAsNumber`. You say in your question that you **only** want the border to turn red when the value of the input is zero, but your code is testing for something else.

Add or remove the `error` class with `classList.add()` or `classList.remove()`.

To turn the outline `red` when there is an error, you need to set the `outline-color` style to `red` otherwise the default focus setting of this will override any `border` color you have applied.

You can see this color effect on the `balance` input field, which shows a black outline when the balance is `0` instead of red, but the background is `pink` to show that the `error` `class` is being applied.

```js
const temperatureElement = document.getElementById('temperature');
const balanceElement = document.getElementById('balance');

temperatureElement.addEventListener('input', handleNumberInput);
balanceElement.addEventListener('input', handleNumberInput);

function handleNumberInput(e) {
  if (e.target.valueAsNumber === 0) {
    e.target.classList.add("error");
  } else {
    e.target.classList.remove("error");
  }
}
```

```css
.temperature.error {
  outline-color: red;
  /* background-color: pink; */
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: red;
}

.balance.error {
  /* outline-color: red; */
  background-color: pink;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="temperature">Temperature</label>
<input id="temperature" class="temperature" type="number" step="1" value="1">
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="balance">Balance</label>
<input id="balance" class="balance" type="number" step="1" value="1">
```